# SRTM DEM data appear mismatching in BW/Saturation or even brightness when gathered

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, srtm

I'm trying to make a DEM data of Algeria as I tried to download about 15 SRTM data but when added on ArcGIS and gathered they appear with diffrent saturation/brightness each, I tried then again to join the rasters with the Mosaic to raster tool, it actually matches but decreases in information detail and harshly in brightness..
https://ibb.co/QCwb50z

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you provide a link to your data source?

Comment: Thanks man
Here's how it looks https://ibb.co/QCwb50z
And here's the source http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a display issue that stems from GIS software defaulting the color scale bounds to match the min and max values displayed in each tile of your DEM. To make them match, simply change the bounds of all of your images to the same values, making sure that you choose min and max that are small and large enough, respectively, to allow for all of the elevation values in the country to be displayed uniquely. In ArcGIS you will want to do this by right clicking the layer in the table of contents, then go to properties->symbology to make the adjustments.

Before:[image: default scales][image: default display]

After: [image: new scales][image]